# Printing an index of an array in MIPS using lb and a value in a register to offset/unaligned address error

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, caesar-cipher

I am writing a program which is essentially (I think) a caesar cipher, however the shift is based off the setup of the keyboard rather than the actual alphabet. So, the entry letters would be:
WERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMQ while i would want it to return 
QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM if that makes sense. If I enter a string W as input, it would return Q. If I entered "JO YJRTR" it would return "HI THERE". I did this by hard coding two arrays into the data section. I take the first character of input and search for it in the first array with a loop and a counter to count what letter I am on.Then I want to use that index/counter to print the same letter from the second array, which should be the "decoded" letter. I am trying to do this using arrays and I think I am close but I have an issue when I try to use the index to pull the letter out of the second array. (I get an unaligned address error) I will put the portion of the code where the issue is below.

```
decode:         #want to add t4th index of arr 2 (in t5) to a string in t3
la $t5, Arr2        
add $t5, $t5, $t4   #move to appropriate index of arr2 ?? THIS CREATES ISSUE 
(I THINK)
sw $t3, 0($t5)      #(THIS IS WHERE PROGRAM STOPS)
addiu $s0, $s0, 1   #move to next letter in input word
lb $t7, 0($s0)      #load next letter of input word
```

I'm not sure if this is enough info but any help is appreciated, im really struggling

Comment: You should post a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue. And also post the exact error message and point out which line of code it refers to.